# Select records where date between current date and current date - 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here's what I'm running now, it should be giving me all the parts that have sold between today and 2 years ago. What's wrong with my query?

```
SELECT PART_ID
FROM CUST_ORDER_LINE
WHERE PROMISE_DATE BETWEEN (GETDATE()) AND (SELECT DATEADD(yyyy, -2, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: what error you are getting or what is the issue

Comment: It just doesn't return any rows, which doesn't make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be in reverse order . the oldest date should come first.

```
SELECT PART_ID
FROM CUST_ORDER_LINE
WHERE PROMISE_DATE BETWEEN (DATEADD(yyyy, -2, GETDATE())) and (GETDATE())
```

Comment: done, just needed the timer to expire, thanks @Ameya Deshpande

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a SELECT in either `(SELECT DATEADD(yyyy, -2, GETDATE()))` it can be just

```
(DATEADD(yyyy, -2, GETDATE()))
```